# Creating a custom login on site.

Tags: wp-login-form

Evening,

I'm trying to make a simple 'login' feature for my site.  I'd rather just have a dropdown box of sorts, and to login, the redirect back to the page you submitted it on.

I've some code I found (I'm VERY new to wordpress), and it doesn't seem to be working right, when I click 'send', nothing changes. The page gives no errors, and it just sits there, it doesn't say I've logged in, or give any indication it's acting different.

```
<?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>
<h2>Login</h2>
<form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>../../wordpress/wp-login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="20" />
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" />
    <p>
       <label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me</label>
       <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<h2>Logout</h2>
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>">logout</a><br />
<a href="http://XXX/wp-admin/">admin</a>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Please can you explain what isn't working correctly?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, when I click 'send', nothing changes.  

The page gives no errors, and it just sits there, it doesn't say I've logged in, or give any indication it's acting different.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your login script is. This is my testscript (saved as ìndex.php`):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testform</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require_once '../wp-load.php';

        var_dump($_COOKIE);

        if ( !( current_user_can('level_0') ) ){
            wp_login_form();
        }
        else { ?>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo home_url('/wp-admin/'); ?>">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

I installed WordPress in a subdirectory on my local server (`testdoma.in/wordpress`). If I install the script in a subdirectory within my WordPress installation (`testdoma.in/wordpress/external`), it works. If I install the script in the root (and change the `require_once` to `wordpress/wp-load.php`), no way to get it working.

If you try to access WordPress functions, the scripts have to be in a subfolder of or directly within your WordPress installation.

**UPDATE**

After some research, it is a cookie problem. The plugin [root Cookie](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/root-cookie/) will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>../../wordpress/wp-login.php" method="post">
```

to this:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/wp-login.php') ?>" method="post">
```

**Updated**:

Consider to use simple `wp_login_form()`. See [wp_login_form reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) for possible function arguments.

```
<?php
if ( !( current_user_can('level_0') ) ){
    wp_login_form();
}
else { ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/wp-admin/'); ?>">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That didn't change anything, after hitting 'send' the page returns, and doesn't indicate a change.  IS this a cookie error?

Comment: @Adola, please see updated code above.

Comment: The same issue persists.  After hitting 'login' the page returns without any indication of loggin in.  It just greets me with the login form again.

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG). And where do you place this form?

Comment: I do not have debugging enabled, and I placed it in /domain/TEST/scripts/php/testWP.php 

Also, I suspect it's a cookie issue, as in, is_user_logged_in() isn't working right.

Comment: So it's not in any of your WordPress theme files? It should be there.  
And also enable debugging during development stage. It helps a lot.

Comment: That's right.  And I went to that codex, and enabled it, but didn't see any warnings or errors.  I don't think I'm using WP_DEBUG right.

Comment: Just place the updated code in any file of WP theme you are using (e. g. `sidebar.php`). Then it should work.  

Regarding WP_DEBUG: when enabled it shows you errors if any. Also if you got no errors with your separate script you should enable `error_reporting` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: That's the thing, I dont't want to use sidebar.php.  Unless I"m missing the point, I don't want any themeing done by wordpress.  I'm only trying to implement the social interactions, and don't need any of the theming.

Comment: To use WordPress function externally you can try to include `wp-load.php` to your script. Search for "wordpress functions outside". Also have a look here: [Don’t include wp-load, please.](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/)

Comment: I included it, but the issue still persists, leading to me to further believe it's some odd cookie behaviour.

Comment: Have you defined `COOKIE_DOMAIN` in your `wp-config.php`? [See here](http://wpengineer.com/2382/wordpress-constants-overview/#security) for a list of WP constants.